# Mostar valores en un arreglo

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio muy sencillo pero que me está liando mucho:

> Crea un programa que pida diez números reales por teclado, los almacene en un array, y
> luego muestre todos sus valores.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numeros[] = new int[10];
        int valores = 0;
        System.out.print("Introduzca 10 dígitos: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
            numeros[i] = sc.nextInt();
            //valores = numeros[i] + numeros[i];
            //valores++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
            if(numeros[i] < valores){
                valores = valores + numeros[i];
                valores++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("El valor del numero introducido es: " + valores);
    }
}
```

Y eso no me da la posición de nada.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: El caso es que me pidieron que cree un programa que me pida 10 números y que me los almacene en un Arry y luego que el Array me muetre los valores de los números que introduje por teclado, pero, no me los muestra.

Comment: Tenés que imprimir los números almacenados en el array, no una suma de ellos (según lo que se lee en el enunciado).

Comment: Es que no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo la verdad llevo con este ejercico 2 horas ya

Comment: Si con un `for` insertaste los valores en el array, con otro `for` los leés...

Comment: Gracías "Padaleina" con tu modificación me ha funcionado.

Comment: Padaleiana** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar el contenido del array que has ido rellenando, tendrías que crear un bucle para recorrer el array "numeros" e ir mostrando la posición deseada de ese array, por ejemplo, para el primer valor: numeros[0]

Te pongo una modificación de tu programa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sample{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int numeros[] = new int[10];
            System.out.print("Introduzca 10 dígitos: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Tecla un número para la posición " + i + ": ");
                numeros[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            for(int n=0; n< numeros.length; n++) System.out.println("El valor del numero introducido en la posición " + n + ": " + numeros[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

En ese último bucle, recorremos el array numeros y vamos mostrando cada una de sus posiciones en memoria.

Comment: Es que ya no sé ni que poner. Yo entiendo q el ejercicio es muy sencillos pero no entiendo nada de java hastaahora, por eso me uní al forro para ir aprendiendo y pidiendo ayuda.

Comment: @Khalifa de hecho, [es.so] _no es un foro_. Y tu problema no era de java, sino más bien de lógica.

Comment: @khalifa no te preocupes. Nadie nace sabiendo y muchas veces recurrir a StackOverflow es el paso "lógico". Es verdad que este problema no era de java propiamente, pero se resuelve igualmente, la idea es que aprendas por qué, no te salían los valores.